# Segmentation fault on for loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a strange behaviour I can't understand... both chunks of code are from the same program... I'm just commenting one or the other... I'm converting a mac address written into a string in a byte array...here's the code that works:

```
unsigned char ssidHex[6];
ssidHex[0] = hexToByte(mac[0], mac[1]);
ssidHex[1] = hexToByte(mac[2], mac[3]);
ssidHex[2] = hexToByte(mac[4], mac[5]);
ssidHex[3] = hexToByte(mac[6], mac[7]);
ssidHex[4] = hexToByte(mac[8], mac[9]);
ssidHex[5] = hexToByte(mac[10], mac[11]);
```

And here's the code that segfaults:

```
unsigned char ssidHex[6];
for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++) 
  ssidHex[y] = hexToByte(mac[y * 2], mac[y * 2 + 1]);
```

As you can see I'm not going outside boundaries... can you please explain me what's wrong?

Thank you very much

**UPDATE**:

The full code is pretty big, anyway "mac" come from the call of the procedure:

```
void compute(char *mac)
```

and comes from the command line, it's a mac address without the double dots, like "DEADDEADDEAD" and here's the definition of hexToByte:

```
unsigned char hexToByte(unsigned char buf1, unsigned char buf2) {
   unsigned char temp[5] = { '0', 'x', buf1, buf2, 0};  
   return strtol(temp, NULL, 0);
}
```

Comment: Please show a complete, compilable, example. That your first code block runs does not necessarily mean it's correct.

Comment: The two codes are equivalent. Perhaps some undefined behavior somewhere?

Comment: Can you put complete code?

Comment: The code looks correct. Try declaring an array "your_type mac[12]" next to the ssidHex array declaration. See if the problem still occurs. Also try mac[ (y * 2) + 1 ] just in case you have a dodgy compiler. These are a long shot but anything is worth trying!

Comment: Given this code, either mac is not declared to have at least 12 elements or hexToByte causes it in some way. We need both definitions (mac and hexToByte) to help. If hexToByte calls non-library functions, we need those too.  It's also possible that completely unrelated code causes it, but that would be harder to help with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @4386427 Btw, you can type `[mcve]` to get a fancy [mcve] link.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - I didn't knew :-) Thanks, I'll try to remember... Testing: [mcve] ... and it worked :-)

Comment: Your [mcve] code doesn't crash at all. Try running under `valgrind` or `gdb` to see where exactly it segfaults. There is a big chance it segfaults after completion of for loop. Have you checked if you were trying to reference the variable `y` as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And here's the code that segfaults

Since there is no real difference between code that works and code that gets `SIGSEGV`, we must conclude that the problem is *elsewhere*.

Unfortunately, you can't show the rest of the code, so we can't tell you where to look either.

If you are on a system that supports Valgrind or AddressSanitizer, it is very likely that one of the tools will tell you *exactly* where your problem is.